# Implement Shopify in iOS app written in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, shopify

I'm relatively new to iOS development and I'm new to Shopify. I'm trying to add a feature to my iOS app (written in Swift) to sell products from a business partner's Shopify store using the Mobile Buy SDK for iOS. I've imported the framework into my app, but am now stuck as I know Swift but not Objective-C and all of the Shopify documentation is written in Objective-C... Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but how can I get a basic store up and running?? Can I use Objective-C code from Shopify's sample app in my Swift app? Or do I need to figure out how to translate a bunch of Objective-C into Swift? Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are ways to implement Objective-C code in Swift. You can look these up on Google. There are also websites that convert Obj-C to Swift. Just search that up and you'll find a few sites which do this for free

Answer (score 0):

Create a bridging header and you can then access it with Swift

Answer (score 0):

Install the library via CocoaPods, and you'll be able to access, all their documentation is still written in Obj-C, but it's not that hard to get the general idea of how to write it in Swift, let me know how you get on!